# toggle menu with one menu open at a time in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I want to make menu toggle and one item from menu is open at a time. I am able to open one item at a time but unable to do toggle at the same time.

```js
var navclick = document.getElementsByClassName("js-dropdown");
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('-arrow-link-content');
for (var i = 0; i < navclick.length; i++) {
    navclick[i].onclick = function () {
      if (this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.contains('nav-active')) {
        this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.remove('nav-active'); 
      }
      else {
        this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.add('nav-active');
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.-arrow-link-content {
  display:none;
}
.nav-active{ display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="c-icons" id="c-iconslist">
                    <li>
                        <div class="c-icons__text js-dropdown">heading 1</div>
                     <div class="c-icons__textdropdown -arrow-link-content"> Content 1</div>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <div class="c-icons__text js-dropdown">heading 2</div>
                     <div class="c-icons__textdropdown -arrow-link-content"> Content 2</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

if anyone have any suggestions.. please share.. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add a  working fiddle or add html markup

Comment: An easy implementation is probably `click on non-open menu item` -> `find and close open menu item` & `open clicked menu item`. No need to loop through your entire list.

Comment: @SwimmerF Can you share some basic example.. i am pretty new to javascript

Comment: @user3342682 I'm not gonna make an example from scratch, if you want code, give code

Comment: @AkhilAravind refer this : https://jsfiddle.net/4hdpvbs6/2/ toggle is working but one menu open at a time is not.

Comment: @SwimmerF refer this : https://jsfiddle.net/4hdpvbs6/2/ toggle is working but one menu open at a time is not.

Comment: @user3342682 check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since at most one element can be open at a time, we just have to look for that one elment and close it first if it exists, before we open an unopened element

```js
var navclick = document.getElementsByClassName("js-dropdown");
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('-arrow-link-content');
for (var i = 0; i < navclick.length; i++) {
    navclick[i].onclick = function () {
      if (this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.contains('nav-active')) {
        this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.remove('nav-active'); 
      }
      else {
        try {
          // if an open element exists, close it first
          this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.nav-active').classList.remove('nav-active');
         }
          catch (error){ 
            // Error occurs when no open elment exists, in that case: Do nothing
          }
        this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.add('nav-active');
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.-arrow-link-content {
  display:none;
}
.nav-active{ display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="c-icons" id="c-iconslist">
                    <li>
                        <div class="c-icons__text js-dropdown">heading 1</div>
                     <div class="c-icons__textdropdown -arrow-link-content"> Content 1</div>
                    </li>
                       <li>
                        <div class="c-icons__text js-dropdown">heading 2</div>
                     <div class="c-icons__textdropdown -arrow-link-content"> Content 2</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

For toggle to work, we need to get all the node with class name `-arrow-link-content`, and then remove the `nav-active` class first, then add `nav-active` to the selected item.

Check the snippet.

```js
var navclick = document.getElementsByClassName("js-dropdown");
var navContent = document.getElementsByClassName('-arrow-link-content');
for (var i = 0; i < navclick.length; i++) {
  navclick[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.contains('nav-active')) {
      this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.remove('nav-active');
      return false
    }


    var el = document.querySelectorAll('div.-arrow-link-content');
    for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
      if (el[i].classList.contains('nav-active')) el[i].classList.remove('nav-active');
    }
    this.parentNode.querySelector('div.-arrow-link-content').classList.add('nav-active');

  }
}
```

```css
.-arrow-link-content {
  display: none;
}

.nav-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-icons" id="c-iconslist">
  <li>
    <div class="c-icons__text js-dropdown">heading 1</div>
    <div class="c-icons__textdropdown -arrow-link-content"> Content 1</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="c-icons__text js-dropdown">heading 2</div>
    <div class="c-icons__textdropdown -arrow-link-content"> Content 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```